# ElasticSearch: aggregate only matched elements of an array

Tags: elasticsearch

In ElasticSearch 6.2, how do I aggregate only those elements from an array that actually match a query? My request looks like this:

```
{
    "query": {
            "bool":{
                    "must":[ 
                           {"prefix":{"titles":"I_match_the"}},
                           {"match":{"database":"EXAMPLE_SOURCE"}}
                    ]
             }
    },
    "size":0,
    "aggs":{
        "aggregatedTitle": {
            "terms":{
                "field":"titles.keyword",
                "size":10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with the response:

```
{
...
"aggregations": {
    "aggregatedTitle": {
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": "I_match_the_query",
                "doc_count": 3
            },
            {
                "key": "I_dont_match_but_lie_in_the_same_array_as_matched_element",
                "doc_count": 3
            },
            {
                "key": "I_dont_match_but_also_lie_in_the_same_array_as_matched_element",
                "doc_count": 3
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

but the buckets in the response contain all elements that are inside the "titles.keyword"-array, not just the one with the key `I_match_the_query`. How do I filter those out so in my example I would get only the first bucket?

I think I have to use a `nested` query, but I am not sure if I also need `inner_hits` like here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/nested.html and if I do, how to aggregate over those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did not ask in the question (I did not know it myself until today) but is required to answer it, is that the property "titles.keyword" should be actually a nested list. Without that configuration, the filtering is not possible. Once you have adjusted your backend, you can make a query like this

```
  "nested":{
     "path":"title",
     "query":{
        "bool":{
           "must":[
              {
                 "term":{
                    "title.keyword":"I_match_the"
                 }
              }
           ]
        }
     },
     "inner_hits": {
        "docvalue_fields" : ["title.keyword"]
     }
  }
```

and then bucket-aggregate over the `fields.title.keyword` value that you receive

Comment: I can successfully use the nested query and inner hits to return only the matching property from the nested object, but what is not obvious from your answer is how to aggregate on the inner_hits docvalue_fields. Can you update your answer to show the aggregation?